# How should I handle blockchain forks in my DApp?

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, forks, blockchain-fork, chain-reorganization

In the user interface of my DApp, how can I detect that a blockchain reorganization happened and what should I do to update the UI state once the fork is resolved?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few modules around that let you keep track of the "state" of a transaction (unconfirmed, X confirmations, conflicting transaction exists and is being confirmed, fully confirmed, definitely failed) and represent this info in the UI with color-coding. You should then probably only make "irreversible" changes to the data that's represented in the UI after a transaction gets to 12 confirmations.

Comment: One of said modules is [reflux-tx](https://github.com/ConsenSys/reflux-tx)

Comment: would like to see a nodejs module.   I'm considering adding the equivalent of reflux-tx to ether-pudding if not, so I can transition application state based on promises.