# How will the number of confirmations for security change with Casper?

Tags: transactions, security, blockchain, consensus, casper

How will this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/319/what-number-of-confirmations-is-considered-secure-in-ethereum) change when Casper is deployed?

Comment: I wonder why it should change?

Comment: I think there is going to be some concept of "finality", and with it there will probably be a clear answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

In general, a "confirmation" of a transaction receipt is an economic assurance or "economic proof" that it is correct.

Casper's "confirmation" strategy is to provide transaction receipts that include the bets that validators have placed on the correctness of receipts (bets on state), and on the guarantee that the transaction will be executed (bets on blocks). A client will choose the receipts that have the most backing from the bonded validators. Once a client sees a finalized receipt, they have reached "maximum security", and they stop choosing between receipts!

Comment: What is a finalized receipt?  (Or should it be a separate question?)