# What is 'the last add pending transaction' in web3 filter?

Tags: web3js, logs, filters, pending-transactions, metamask

I run this code using MetaMask to inject web3 object:

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter('pending');
filter.watch(function (error, log) {
  console.log(log);  
});
```

From web3 api [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter):

> When using the "pending" parameter, it returns a transaction hash of the last add pending transaction.

My log looks like this:

[image]

I can't fing anything that would look like a **transaction hash of the last add pending transaction**.

I'm not sure if it's an issue with MetaMask. Could anyone running the node please run this code and post here the **log**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/filters-whats-latest-and-pending) about `pending`:

> `Pending` is the collection of transactions that can be executed by
>   the network (that your own node knows about), but have not yet been
>   done so.

If your node sends a transaction, you should see its transaction hash being logged.  Send a second transaction, and you should see its hash.

This documentation may be clearer as: `When using the "pending" parameter, it returns a transaction hash of the most recent pending transaction.`

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Just to be clear, this code logs the last pending transactions that only my node sends? Is there a way to log the pending transactions that other nodes send?

Comment: I think it should also log pending transactions that other nodes send to your node.

Comment: As it turned out, the problem was that MetaMask doesn't support "pending" filters yet. When I connected to Geth at local host everything worked just fine.

Comment: @EugeneEpifanov Thank you for clarifying that the current issue is lack of support from MetaMask; hopefully they will fix in time.