# Inconsistency in web3.eth.getBlock

Tags: transactions, web3js, receipts

I'm indexing transactions as they are confirmed. I poll the web3.eth.getBlock with the next number and I put them in a database.
But, I've realized that some transactions have an incorrect block number. I suppose that the problem is that I've got the incorrect block branch and finally another branch was the one kept in the blockchain. 
How I can prevent this situation? web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt can prevent this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

**A.** You can wait for further block confirmations before writing to your database.  It's like being X minutes behind, so that you don't have to deal with a chain reorg.  See [What number of confirmations is considered secure in Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/319/what-number-of-confirmations-is-considered-secure-in-ethereum) and note one of the answers is to combine waiting and use multiple clients.

**B.** If you want to deal with chain reorgs, you can indeed make use of `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` and for example code see:
[How can a DApp detect a fork or chain reorganization using web3.js or additional libraries?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-can-a-dapp-detect-a-fork-or-chain-reorganization-using-web3-js-or-additional)