# how can I get the data returned from solidity function from transaction id in web3js when a solidity function is callled?

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, blockchain, ethereumjs

I want to get the return data written in solidity function in web3js .
I am using the `web3.min.js` from the truffle pet-shop package as the web3 library . Everything is working fine when calling the function it is returning the transaction data from which I used `web3.eth.getTransactionReciept` to get the details and the gas is also used. Now I want the data which is returning
my solidity method

```
 function helloworld() public returns (string) {
        return "helloworld";
    }
```

The js part

```
<script>

    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));
    }
    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
    console.log('web3.eth.accounts :', web3.eth.accounts);
    var walletContractJSONabiGlobal;
    $.getJSON('./contracts/Wallet.json',async function(walletContractJSONabi) {
        walletContractJSONabiGlobal = walletContractJSONabi;
        var walletContract = web3.eth.contract(walletContractJSONabi.abi);
        var walletInstance = walletContract.at('0xc74c8d941494495a4f65c42bebc556398e1f028d');
        walletInstance.helloworld((err,data)=>{
            if (err) {
                console.log('err :', err);
            } else {
                console.log('data :', data);
            }
        })

    })

</script>
```

I getting the data in console

> data :
>   0x988d4bd3169a4d752f6e4ac230d01840f2f7b4cc8e87d768a8e41b6fe867740d

I did the `web3.toAscii(this transaction is)` but it is not coming proper result which is expected as this is not a hex value

When output of `web3.eth.getTransactionReciept`

> blockHash :
>   "0x552a93b0035571b93e4a1a89daa445663b0ddb29974078cdf9a250b7f873ca96"
>   blockNumber : 10 contractAddress : null cumulativeGasUsed : 21899
>   gasUsed : 21899 logs : [] logsBloom :
>   "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
>   status : "0x01" transactionHash :
>   "0x988d4bd3169a4d752f6e4ac230d01840f2f7b4cc8e87d768a8e41b6fe867740d"
>   transactionIndex : 0

Please Help in this Thank YOu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be marked as a duplicate, so just to help you out. You can't.

The return values are only available to other contracts. As a software client signing and sending a transaction, you get a transaction receipt and then after waiting for the transaction to be mined, you can inspect the logs of inspect other functions on a read-only basis (either the contract function is `view` or `pure`, or you invoke it with the JavaScript `.call()` method) to discover what's new in the contract state. The return values of the state-changing function are out of reach.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How to get the mined status? I did the `.call()` but it was coming undefined method then  I figured it out that I was using the old web3 I upgraded it and now the `.call()` is working.

Comment: This is nicely solved with Truffle but there is more learning curve to get used to it. Among other things, they wrap the contract ABI in a higher-level abstraction that cleans up the syntax and deals with details like this. Have a look over here for practical ideas. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/optimal-way-of-waiting-for-transactions-to-be-mined-in-geth

Comment: Its wierd  in general cause My UI depends on the return datas and if in a deployed env if no one is there to mine then Its really hard to get the things going. it ok for local development env . The things are quite clear for me now . Thanks