# Solidity returning address to javascript when uint was requested

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm early in learning solidity (that's probably obvious). No idea why I'm getting this result.

medsToBeDeveloped has a length of 0 at begining

```
 uint [] medsToBeDeveloped;

 function returnProductID() external returns(uint){
    uint randNum = medsToBeDeveloped.length;
    medsToBeDeveloped.push(randNum);
    potentialMedsToManufacturer[randNum] = msg.sender;
    return(randNum);
}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#requestID").on('click', function(){
announceButton("request ID");
contract.returnProductID(function(err, id){
  console.log(typeof id);
  console.log("id: " + parseInt(id) + " thatis all");
  });
})
```

I'm probably doing something very obvious

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting a transaction hash and mistaking it for an address.

This function changes the state and therefore results in a transaction sent to the network for verification. You would have to wait for the transaction to be mined and then access a `view` function to see the result.

The first async response is the transaction hash that you can use to await confirmation. Monitoring that transaction for confirmations is a separate client-side concern.

This admittedly brief explanation will raise some new questions, like how to wait for it to be mined. This might help: [What's the proper way to wait for a transaction to be mined and get the results?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9636/whats-the-proper-way-to-wait-for-a-transaction-to-be-mined-and-get-the-results)

And what is a `view` function? https://blog.b9lab.com/calls-vs-transactions-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-62d6b17d0bc2

Hope it helps.