# Storing transactions result into database

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions, database

I need to store the transaction details to my database. And here is my code:

```
    var rawTx = {
        nonce: nonce,
        gas: estimate_gas,
        to: contract_add,
        value: '0x0',
        data: dataField,
        chainId: 4
    };
    web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTx, privateKey, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) {
              // Store err to database here
                 ...
        }
        else {
            web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(hash.rawTransaction)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log("DONE SENDING");
                    // Save res to Database here
                    ...
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("FAILED SENDING");
                    // Save error to Database here
                    ...
                });
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
      // Save err to Database here
         ...
}
```

The code is works for me, except when `sendSignedTransaction` catch an `error` that transaction was not mined in 750second. I know the transaction is still processing even this timeout error occurs.

But the critical problem here is further transactions will getting stuck in the pending, and get the same timeout `error` in my code. These transaction need to wait in pending until the previous transactions success.

After the first transaction success, geth will continue process the pending transactions in node, but execute them without go through my code above, so I can't store the transaction result into my database now.

Is there any solution for this? Or there is some callback in geth when a transaction done so I could use this callback to store the transaction result?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9636/whats-the-proper-way-to-wait-for-a-transaction-to-be-mined-and-get-the-results     you can use this npm package :  https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-transaction-mined

Answer (score 1):

If you are using web3js 1.0, you can fix it quiet easily. In web3js 1.0, you can listen to the event of the transaction got mined into the block. So after that you can send next transaction based on the success status of the mined transaction. This success status you can get from the transaction receipt of that particular transaction. But, point to be noted that before getting mined in the blockchain, you will get null as transaction receipt if you explicitly call api to get transaction receipt.

The way of tx sending you can follow according to the given pic. There, in on receipt received, you will send your next transaction. The same process will be triggered for the next transactions.

To get further explanation, go through the link below
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-eth.html#id64[image]