# How to check if an event is confirmed?

Tags: events, confirmations

When an event is triggered, you get something like this:

```
{
  "address": "0x0a7a177321f3b3b6e2299e621eb32e892b141b4b",
  "topics": [
"0x0d332ed5c7d6f1999116748c0eb99c740f276d879d025a5be6435fcf177785de"
  ],
  "data": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000568616c6c6f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "blockNumber": "0x2f6d30",
  "transactionHash": "0x4aaf274a399ee315dc351b30b2e6ff9525996d4700c4843ec0a625512cd21fd1",
  "transactionIndex": "0x4",
  "blockHash": "0xbfad930ed694aae9fc660951ac4a309701a17e75f02087c72c3ea78431c3005e",
  "logIndex": "0x2",
  "removed": false
}
```

I need to know if the event has been confirmed and it won't be "reverted" (at least with a high confidence level).

What I was thinking on doing was to wait for the block referenced in `blockHash` to have 12 confirmations to considered the event confirmed.

In order to check the 12 confirmations, my guess is that I need to check the block by calling `eth_getBlockByHash`, verify the response is not `null` (which I guess would mean the block was discarded) and make sure that `eth_blockNumber - block.number` is equals or bigger than 12.

Does this process to confirm an event sounds correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, waiting for [block confirmations](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/319/what-number-of-confirmations-is-considered-secure-in-ethereum) is how to ensure that an event exists.

Yes, `eth_getBlockByHash` will return `null` when a block is discarded.

There's some sample code in [How can a DApp detect a fork or chain reorganization using web3.js or additional libraries?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-can-a-dapp-detect-a-fork-or-chain-reorganization-using-web3-js-or-additional)  (Quality answers that are added to it will get upvoted, and may also become the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The method most people choose for what is considered "confirmed" is waiting for an *(x)* amount of blocks to be mined since the transaction you are checking for.

The longer you wait, the better since it reduces the chance that a transaction becomes an "uncle'd" or is reverted.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the way to do it. In my question I wanted to know if that applies for events as well and also if the way to do it is by checking the existence of the block, because I don't know very well what happens when a block is discarded. Is it still there with a flag indicating it was discarded or is it removed completely, meaning that calling `eth_getBlockByHash` will return `null`?