# eth_getTransactionReceipt with null block hash

Tags: json-rpc, receipts, openethereum

I am getting receipts with `null` for `blockHash` and `blockNumber`.

That means I am somehow getting a receipt before the block is mined.

Is this an expected result?

If so, what is the use of it?

Comment: Here is one use of the receipt: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/how-can-a-dapp-detect-a-fork-or-chain-reorganization-using-web3-js-or-additional