# How is transaction finality correlated with transacted amount?

Tags: blockchain, security, economics

It was argued by Vitalik Buterin that [transaction security can be a function of the amount the transaction carries](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/09/14/on-slow-and-fast-block-times/). This is because of the economics of attacks.

How many block confirmations would you say are just a block confirmation too few for the given amounts:

1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000 USD?

Comment: Isn't it almost the same question as http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/319/405 ?

Comment: No because risk of variability depending on the among at stake. Very interesting for balancing risk and usability problems with time lag

Comment: I think it depends on what attack type you fear about. If we talk about 51% attack, you are safe until the transaction amount is less than the cost of attacking. If you talk about a yet unknown attack, then we'll it's unknown  I think that we can't tell an absolute safety level of confirmation. It depends on so much unknown things as an attack will not only use the normal protocol flaws as 51% attack but will try to exploit other vulnerabilities that would make your transaction at risk whatever the amount and the confirmation count.