# Transaction Confirmations in the transactions log

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, confirmations

I setup a private net where only 4 nodes are connected. But when I am doing transactions and checking my transactions log. I am getting hundreds of confirmations.
Who can see my private Ethereum blockchain transactions and confirming it?

Answer (score 4):

Actually confirmations showing in the transactions log are the number of block added over the block containing same transaction. So you can get hundreds of confirmations in a 4 node private net. It's fine.

For more detail on confirmation : [What number of confirmations is considered secure in Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/319/what-number-of-confirmations-is-considered-secure-in-ethereum)

Answer (score 1):

if your nodes mine blocks (miner.*) so you will get these confirmations no one else is doing that for you. one new block added is a one more confirmation.
to check which nodes you are connected use `admin.peers` or `net.peerCount` to get the number of the connected nodes.