# Why does web3.getBalance sometimes return old value?

Tags: web3js, balances

Can anyone please explain the following issue? I have a pretty simple code to fetch ETH balance using the `web3` JS library. It's something like the following:

```
import Web3 form 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://api.myetherapi.com/eth'));
const batch = new web3.eth.BatchRequest();

batch.add(api.eth.getBalance.request('0x...', 'latest', (err, balance) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether');
    }
}));

...

batch.execute();
```

I call this code every N seconds, and it works fine most of the time. However, when some transaction changes the balance, a weird thing happens: `getBalance` may return either new balance or old one. I mean, one call will return a new value, the next call - old value, then new value again and so on.

Is there any kind of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior can happen due to forks in the chain. The best practice is to wait for a transaction until you have 12 confirmations (blocks). See "[What number of confirmations is considered secure in Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/319/what-number-of-confirmations-is-considered-secure-in-ethereum)"

**EDIT**
Ethereum just like Bitcoin implements probabilistic BFT. This means that there is no point in time where you can be 100,0% sure about what you're getting from the chain. For this reason, if you want stable values, you should query these from currentBlock-12.. you can do this via eth.getBalance(addr, eth.blockNumber-12)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But all I want is to get the current balance; I don't see a way to check that all affecting transactions have already been confirmed 12 times.

Comment: Ethereum just like Bitcoin implements probabilistic BFT. This means that there is no point in time where you can be 100,0% sure about what you're getting from the chain. For this reason, if you want stable values, you should query these from currentBlock-12.. you can do this via eth.getBalance(addr, eth.blockNumber-12)