# What happens with transaction after the block fork?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, forks

Do I need to generate transaction again after fork?
How many confirmations are minimal to be sure of the transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction will need to be mined again as is likely that it will be still in the txpool of other nodes. In my experience, whenever a transaction is in an orphaned block I had to submit it again.

As for the number of transactions, 12 transactions is considered safe. See the accepted answer for [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/319/what-number-of-confirmations-is-considered-secure-in-ethereum) for more details on the number of confirmations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Yes, you need to submit the transaction again` can you provide a source for this claim?

Comment: I just updated the answer because as you seem to suggest, it may be the case that the transactions are still in the txpool of other nodes. In my experience, I always had to submit the transaction again.

Comment: I did not know that, my knowledge is pretty theoretical. It is good to  know how does it work in practice, thank you for the insight ^^

Comment: Can you comment on what should happen in theory, that will give me the chance to learn from what you know.

Comment: The answer you give now, is perfectly fine with my understanding: theoretically, it should be no reason to cancel a transaction from the pool until it is not confirmed, maybe the implementation make some speculations to spare space.