# How can i detect the blockchain fork event?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain-fork

[How should I handle blockchain forks in my DApp?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/183/how-should-i-handle-blockchain-forks-in-my-dapp)

In this question, a module named  reflux-tx is introduced, which can help to trace the transaction state and watch for the blockchain fork event.

But my project is written in python. Is there exists something similar to reflux-tx implemented in python?

Cause i'm on my ethereum browser project, so it's necessary to find the blockchain fork event to update my database.

Is there any can help me? Thanks for your advices !